# Select case com expressão e setando o resultado do else

Tags: sql, sql-server

Pessoal alguem pode me ajudar com um problema de select case, eu preciso fazer um select de uma expressão e se essa expressão der um resultado negativo, ele me mostra o valor, caso seja positivo o valor tem que ser alterado para zero, mas eu não to conseguindo ta dando erro na hora de mudar o valor pra zero, e o meu alias pra dar nome pra tabela tmb não funciona, segue a query abaixo:

```
select case 
when DATEDIFF(MINUTE,HR_ENTRADA,HR_SAIDA) - DATEDIFF(MINUTE,HR_SAIDA_ALMOCO,HR_ENTRADA_ALMOCO )  < 0 
then (select DATEDIFF(MINUTE,HR_ENTRADA,HR_SAIDA) - DATEDIFF(MINUTE,HR_SAIDA_ALMOCO,HR_ENTRADA_ALMOCO ) as saldo)
else
    set saldo = 0
end
from TB_REGISTRO_PONTO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pelo que entendi você não esta enviando as opções de resposta para o mesmo atributo e sim para atributos diferentes, tende com esse código, ou se possível disponibilize umas linhas de resultados para exemplo.

```
select case 
when DATEDIFF(MINUTE,HR_ENTRADA,HR_SAIDA) - 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,HR_SAIDA_ALMOCO,HR_ENTRADA_ALMOCO )  < 0 
then (select DATEDIFF(MINUTE,HR_ENTRADA,HR_SAIDA) - 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,HR_SAIDA_ALMOCO,HR_ENTRADA_ALMOCO ))
else
    0
end as saldo
from TB_REGISTRO_PONTO
```

Comment: Opa acertou em cheio, era isso mesmo que tava errado ja consegui aqui, muito obrigado!!